Create shapefile using fiona geopandas succeed but no feature created
From my script I want to create a shapefile from object detection, when the file is small or medium size (under 150.000 features) its workable, but when it more than that value, the feature is null in the shapefile produced, there is my code :
    for objek in result.object_prediction_list:
        if objek.category.id == 0:
            objek.category.id = "Sakit"
        elif objek.category.id == 1:
            objek.category.id = "Sehat"

        x_min = objek.bbox.minx
        y_min = objek.bbox.miny
        x_max = objek.bbox.maxx
        y_max = objek.bbox.maxy

        radius_pixel = int((y_max - y_min) / 2)
        radius_geo = pixel_to_geospatial_distance(radius_pixel, transform)

        x_centroid = (x_min + x_max) / 2
        y_centroid = (y_min + y_max) / 2
        lon, lat = image_to_geospatial_coordinates(x_centroid, y_centroid, transform)
        deteksi_geospasial.append((lon, lat))
        kelas_deteksi.append(objek.category.id)
        radius_list.append(radius_geo)

        class_counts[objek.category.id] += 1

    temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()

    shp_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    path_shp = os.path.join(shp_path, 'Aresta.shp')
    gdf_blok_sap = gpd.read_file(path_shp)

    gdf_deteksi = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=[Point(lon, lat) for lon, lat in deteksi_geospasial],
        crs=crs
    )
    gdf_deteksi['KELAS'] = kelas_deteksi
    gdf_deteksi['RADIUS'] = radius_list

    # Handle NaN values
    if gdf_deteksi.isnull().values.any():
        print("Warning: There are NaN values in the data, filling with mean")
        gdf_deteksi['RADIUS'] = gdf_deteksi['RADIUS'].fillna(gdf_deteksi['RADIUS'].mean())

    gdf_deteksi['geometry'] = gdf_deteksi.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.buffer(row.RADIUS), axis=1)
    
    gdf_blok_sap = gdf_blok_sap.to_crs(crs)

    gdf_joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf_deteksi, gdf_blok_sap, how='left', predicate='within')
    gdf_joined['RADIUS'] = gdf_joined['RADIUS'] * 111320
    gdf_joined = gdf_joined[['geometry', 'RADIUS', 'KELAS', 'ESTATE', 'DIVISI', 'BLOK_SAP', 'TANAM']]

    tmpfile_name = os.path.join(temp_dir, "temp_shapefile.shp")
    gdf_joined.to_file(tmpfile_name, driver="ESRI Shapefile")

    return tmpfile_name, class_counts['Sakit'], class_counts['Sehat']

There is some regulation of maximum features created from geopandas fiona in shapefile?
Or should be better using geopackage? Any advice?

Are any of shapefile component files greater than 2GB in the > 150,000 features output?  If so, that's likely your problem. Shapefiles are an ancient format and are limited to 2GB file sizes http://switchfromshapefile.org/

Thanks for your renspons,
i think my shapefile size is not up to 2 GB, cause the previus processing using file size that is 3/4 of size file im processing now, produces file less than 200 mb and features output 120.000.

You could try specifying an extra parameter engine="pyogrio" in to_file, and indeed, using GPKG instead of shp is also a very good idea...
